# How can I read from files in UTF-16LE encoding in PHP?

Tags: php, csv, utf-16, utf-16le

I've got [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files in [UTF-16LE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte-order_encoding_schemes) encoding with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). They might be pretty big, so I don't really like the idea of reading whole files in memory. How do I go about reading them?

Answer (score 4):

Read it line by line and use [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php):

```
$decoded_line = mb_convert_encoding ($line, "UTF-8", "UTF-16LE");
```

You can choose any destination encoding, but I'm assuming you want to work with UTF-8 strings, which are the most common nowadays.

This function needs the [mbstring](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) extension to be enabled.

You can then pass the decoded line to the [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) function which returns an array representing the current line.

Comment: Another panda!!! Well problem is to read line by line, fgets() won't work with UTF16

Comment: I suppose using `stream_get_line` using the litteral UTF-16LE line feed character '0x00 0x0A' might work.

Comment: I believe your solution would be perfect if not for `stream_get_line`'s `$length` parameter. Test code for [my `1.txt` file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27551630/52499): `$fh = fopen(PRJ_ROOT . '1.txt', 'r'); fread($fh, 2); $s = stream_get_line($fh, 1000, "\x0d\x00\x0a\x00"); printf("%s\n", to_hex($s)); $s = stream_get_line($fh, 1000, "\x0d\x00\x0a\x00"); printf("%s\n", to_hex($s)); $s = stream_get_line($fh, 1000, "\x0d\x00\x0a\x00"); var_dump($s);`

Comment: Well the $length parameter can be seen as a safeguard so you don't end up using more memory than you want to. The documentation does not say if -1 or 0 hold significant values, which is odd considering there are other PHP functions that allow "unlimited" lengths by the use of such values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
class readutf16le_filter extends php_user_filter {
    function filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing) {
        while ($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in)) {
            # printf("filter: %s\n", to_hex($bucket->data));
            $bucket->data = iconv('UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8',
                strlen($bucket->data) && substr($bucket->data, 0, 2) == "\xff\xfe"
                    ? substr($bucket->data, 2)
                    : $bucket->data);
            $consumed += $bucket->datalen;
            stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);
        }
        return PSFS_PASS_ON;
    }
}

stream_filter_register('readutf16le', 'readutf16le_filter');

$fh = fopen('1.txt', 'r');
stream_filter_append($fh, 'readutf16le');

$s = fgets($fh);
printf("%s\n", to_hex($s));

$s = fgets($fh);
printf("%s\n", to_hex($s));

$s = fgets($fh);
var_dump($s);
```

File *1.txt*:

```
a
b
```

Output:

```
filter: ff fe 61 00 0d 00 0a 00 62 00 0d 00 0a 00
61 0d 0a
62 0d 0a
bool(false)
```

What I still don't like is that I don't see any way to detect the beginning of the file in the filter. However, it's unlikely to cause problems. Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark):

> BOM use is optional, and, if used, should appear at the start of the text stream.
>
> If the BOM character appears in the middle of a data stream, Unicode says it should be interpreted as a "zero-width non-breaking space" (inhibits line-breaking between word-glyphs). In Unicode 3.2, this usage is deprecated in favour of the "Word Joiner" character, U+2060.[1] This allows U+FEFF to be only used as a BOM.
>
> For the IANA registered charsets UTF-16BE and UTF-16LE, a byte order mark should not be used because the names of these character sets already determine the byte order. If encountered anywhere in such a text stream, U+FEFF is to be interpreted as a "zero width no-break space".

Probably this can be done with a stream wrapper. One can probably do `fread($fh, 2);` before appending a filter to the stream.

And the other possible issue is that `strlen($bucket->data)` might theoretically be an odd number. From what I can tell, PHP uses buffering and it's unlikely to run into a buffer of size being an odd number (usually they are powers of 2). But to accommodate such cases:

```
...
while ($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in)) {
    $data = strlen($bucket->data) ?
        substr($bucket->data, 0, floor(strlen($bucket->data) / 2) * 2) : '';
    $bucket->data = iconv('UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8',
        strlen($data) && substr($data, 0, 2) == "\xff\xfe"
            ? substr($data, 2)
            : $data);
    $consumed += strlen($data);
    stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);
    ...
```

I don't know how to reproduce this though.